# Mysql insert if not available, update if partial available and exit if fully available

Tags: mysql

i need to take the appropriate action depending on whether the values are found, partially found or not available at all.

This is my table:

```
id. emp_code. ot_date. ot_hours
 1 123      2021-05-01 3
 2 567      2021-05-01 1
```

Now i have these 3 data:

**Data #1**
emp_code: 123
ot_date: 2021-05-01
ot_hours: 3

**Data #2**
emp_code: 123
ot_date: 2021-05-02
ot_hours: 3

**Data #3**
emp_code: 567
ot_date: 2021-05-01
ot_hours: 2.5

This is my logic to decide and take action:

```
 select emp_code, ot_date where values are (emp_code, ot_date)
 from ot_forecast
 if it exist
 select emp_code, ot_dat,ot_hours where values are (emp_code, ot_date, ot_hours)
 from ot_forecast
 if exist then exit
 else update values (emp_code, ot_date, ot_hours)
 else insert values (emp_code, ot_date, ot_hours)
```

Based on my logic, data 1 will be skipped, data 2 will be inserted and data 3 will be updated

Problem is, I can't figure out how to put this in codes. I'm already stuck at the first line.

Hope someone can guide me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create `emp_code`,`ot_date` as a unique (or primary (`id` seems pointless)) key, that enables [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ot_forecast ( emp_code, ot_date)
```

Your query will become:

```
INSERT INTO ot_forecast
SET emp_code = xxx, ot_date= yyyy, ot_hours = zzzz
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ot_hours = zzzz
```

The first case of yours as the select will incur an update and maybe this is ok as its effectively a no-op.

If you where using MariaDB you could also use [INSERT RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/):

```
INSERT INTO ot_forecast
SET emp_code = xxx, ot_date= yyyy, ot_hours = zzzz
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ot_hours = zzzz
RETURNING emp_code, ot_date, ot_hours
```

Comment: Fantastic solution! works perfectly. Thank you